# Http GET request in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, get, request

How can I get JSON from http get request in javascript? The URL is:

```
    http://www.streamfinder.com/api/?api_codekey=[devkey]&do=get_genre_list&return_data_format=json
```

I have already tried a lot of stuff, but none of them seem to work... I have tried this, but it is also not working.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: The search keyword you are looking for is "Ajax" (assuming you mean client side JS in a web page)

Comment: You make an XHR request. There's copious information online describing how to do this.

Comment: I have already tried all of that stuff, its not working.

Comment: @user1176999 — What does your JavaScript error console say?

Comment: That's a cross domain call which you can only perform if the remote server allows it which that one does not.  Try [jsonp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).

Comment: Thanks Alex, the problem was that i was using json instead of jsonp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was using json instead of jsonp. The code that worked is this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "URL",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(res) {

            alert(JSON.stringify(res));
        }

    });
```